# Can't Access Logs from Spark UI on HDInsight cluster

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight

I have deployed a new HDInsight 3.6 cluster with Spark 2.1 installed.  I have previously used an HDInsight 3.5 cluster with Spark 1.6.

On this new cluster, I'm unable to access the executor logs from the Spark UI.  Typically, in my previous (3.5 / 1.6) clusters, I have gone to the `Executors` tab and then clicked on `stderr` for the stdout logs from an individual executor.

What configuration could be causing this issue, or is there a workaround?  I'm submitting a pyspark application if it makes a difference. Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any error message, when you click on stderr?

Comment: ```This site can’t be reached

10.0.0.4 took too long to respond.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT```

from Chrome

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem recently and we downloaded the logs to the filesystem using the following command through SSH:

```
yarn logs -applicationId <Application ID> -out <path_to_local_folder>
```

More information [here](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.4/bk_yarn-resource-management/content/ch_yarn_cli_view_running_applications.html).

Then we downloaded the logs from a VM using WinSCP and analysed them there.

Here's how it looks from WinSCP:

[WinSCP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUy4k.png)

[WinSCP - Containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VR7u.png)

Download those files, maybe split them and you can analyse them.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the logs files from the application view, you can drill down further to find out the containers associated with the application and the logs (stdout/stderr). You can also launch the Spark UI by clicking the linking corresponding to the Tracking URL, as shown below.
[image]

Click the **Executors** tab to see processing and storage information for each executor. You can also retrieve the call stack by clicking on the **Thread Dump** link.

[image]

Comment: Those are the driver logs, not the executor logs.  I have an application that works fine in local driver mode, but fails in yarn cluster mode, so this doesn't allow me to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a URL rewrite issue if you are accessing Spark UI without SSH tunnel. Try to refresh the page, or close/reopen browser window.

Alternatively, if the error persists, you can connect to the Spark UI using SSH tunnel. See this documentation on how to connect using SSH tunnel: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-linux-ambari-ssh-tunnel